# FB Login doesn't launch window

Tags: facebook, authentication

FB.login() seems to execute but the popup window doesn't launch

Answer (score 0):

You did not offer any additional information about the problem, such as errors if any, how you're calling *FB.login* and any relevant code.

I'll guess that maybe you're trying to call this method automatically and not after a user action.
In the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) it says:

> Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup
>   window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click
>   event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.

So if you're not calling it after a mouse click the popup will be blocked.
Is that the case?

Comment: ..or if the user's already connected before, you wouldn't even notice a popup xD

Comment: If it answered your question, please be sure to accept the answer.